# How can I make a BorderLayout fill the screen?

Tags: codenameone

I have a border layout, but it only takes the natural size of it's components within - I'd like the South part to be at the bottom of the screen, not just underneath the centre.

If I can make the containers in the middle fill all available screen width that would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surrounding layout is giving the border layout its preferred size. You should place the border layout in the center of a border layout or as the top level layout.

Comment: You guys are awesome. And so is Codename One :)